# PostgreSQL outputs different TimeStamp format than Javascript TimeStamp format

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, timestamp, pg

I'm having trouble binding the results from SQL to my Model in `Javascript /Typescript`.

In my model, I have a property of `created_at` with types of `Date`.

When I use JSON functions in the Postgres SQL statement to avoid duplicate parent rows for a relationship, I will get a different format for the timestamp.

Here is a simple example

```
SELECT
   a.*,
   (
      SELECT
         ROW_TO_JSON(profile) 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               *
            FROM
               profile p 
            WHERE
               p.account_id = a.id 
         )
         profile 
   )
   AS profile 
FROM
   account a 
WHERE
   a.id = 16
```

And here are the results in JSON

```
{
   "id":16,
   "email":"test@gmail.com",
   "password":"$password",
   "role_id":0,
   "created_at":"2020-04-01T22:03:44.324Z",
   "profile":{
      "id":8,
      "username":"firmanjml",
      "gender":0,
      "bio":null,
      "avatar":"www.firmanjml.me/test.jpg",
      "account_id":16,
      "created_at":"2020-04-02T06:03:44.32498"
   }
}
```

I noticed that the parent row which is from the account table has the Z at the end of `created_at` whereas the child table that is converted to JSON has a different timestamp format.

Is there a way that I could make all the timestamp be in `Javascript` format?

Query to create schema and insert data

```
CREATE TABLE "account"(
    id SERIAL primary key,
    email varchar(50) not null,
    password varchar(50) not null,
    role_id int2 default 0 not null, 
    created_at timestamp default now() not null
);

CREATE TABLE "profile"(
    id SERIAL primary key,
    username varchar(50) not null,
    gender int2 not null,
    bio varchar(50),
    avatar varchar(50),
    account_id integer not null REFERENCES account (id),
    created_at timestamp default now() not null
);

INSERT INTO "account" (email,"password","role_id",created_at) VALUES 
('test@gmail.com','$password',0,'2020-04-02 06:03:44.324');

INSERT INTO "profile" (username,gender,bio,avatar,account_id,created_at) VALUES 
('fimrnajml',0,NULL,'www.firmanjml.me/test.jpg',1,'2020-04-02 06:03:44.324');
```

Comment: The JS timestamp is wrong by my definition. 'Z' is a timezone, and unless you're using it EVERYWHERE then you should mark it as such.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. My typescript model can only bind the rows data if the timestamp comes with the Z, the rest of the created_at will give me an error. I want all the timestamp to have the 'Z' symbol.

Without the Z, it will detect it as invalid DateTime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TO_CHAR() function to format the timestamp in your SQL, like https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_char/

A format of 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US"Z"' should do it. This assumes all your timestamps are in UTC (the way the pros do it :-)

Your SQL then looks like:

```sql
SELECT
   a.*,
   (
      SELECT
         ROW_TO_JSON(profile) 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               username,gender,bio,avatar,account_id,to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US"Z"') created_at
            FROM
               profile p 
            WHERE
               p.account_id = a.id 
         )
         profile 
   )
   AS profile 
FROM
   account a
WHERE
   a.id = 16
```

try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tCmQFvP243syw83qUGszzh/1)

Comment: 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"' Fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes .MS"Z" fixed the issue. Why converting to JSON strips away "Z" at the end? Postgres by default sends it out with "Z" for regular UTC timestamp.

Comment: The "Z" sets the time zone of the timestamp explicitly to UTC. The default behavior is not to set a time zone at all, and PostgreSQL assumed the system time zone is the correct one (I think, it's been awhile). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators